# Creating a [qtcore] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

I have been considering for a while to create a [qtcore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtcore) tag on Stack Overflow. My main objective was twofold:

1. Consistency: this would be in line with the existing Qt Project module tags, such as:

   [qtgui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtgui)
   [qtnetwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtnetwork)
   [qtsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtsql)
   [qtmultimedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtmultimedia)
   [qtscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtscript)
   [qtwebkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtwebkit)
   , etc.
2. Convenience: it is easier for me to go to the core questions about the Qt Project as opposed to a mix as I have now. It is not that bad, so I do not dislike it per se, but I think this minor improvement could make my life and probably others' a bit improved(?) :-)

I was reading the question below. I had a quick discussion in there with [@Bill the Lizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard).

*[What's the stance on Class-specific tags to questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112008/whats-the-stance-on-class-specific-tags-to-questions)*

One unfortunate consequence is that it requires some manual power to update some old questions if the contributors wish so. There is no automated mechanism like a "tagging hierarchy" that could be of some help in here. There are several QtCore based class tags around, like [qthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qthread), [qvector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qvector), [qlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qlist), [qregexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qregexp), [qstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qstring), [qchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qchar), et al. I do not personally use class tags that much, but based on previous threads like the aforementioned, it might be better to keep them around, although I am willing to listen to what others think.

You can read a couple of useful questions below about tag hierarchy questions in the past. Note, this is not the topic of this question to be discussed. I am accepting the decision about it that has happened on meta.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=tag+hierarchy

What do others think about this idea?

Comment: I think that some class-specific tags are OK, I'm ambivalent about them at the moment. I'm sure though that they should be used in connection with the module-specific tag. I'm all for creation of the latter.

Comment: A [qtcore] tag seems like a fair enough idea. It would certainly be a convenient grouping for those interested in that particular part of Qt. One additional inconvenience however is the bumping that would be the result of such a (re-)tagging. So if this idea is agreed upon, the tagging would have to happen gradually, and ideally taking the whole of the post into account, fixing everything that's necessary.

Comment: I support the idea to have tags for each (or most) Qt modules, this should improve question organisation. I am not sure about class-specific tags, `qthread` or `qregexp` sound reasonable to me, but I'd prefer tag hierarchy for them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there are tags for all of the other modules, then there should definitely be one for qtcore.