# Implied tags (e.g. asp.net implies .net)

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-hierarchy

Often, one tag implies another:

- asp.net => .net
- asp.net-mvc-5 => asp.net-mvc => asp.net => .net
- c# => .net
- t-sql => sql-server

Sometimes, some of these tags are forgotten by the OP and nobody adds them later (examples on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net).

This is a problem for:

1. Search
2. Tag pages and tag searches
3. Subscribing to tags
4. Mjölnir Close Hammer
5. Awarded tag badges
6. Search engines
7. Surely others

There should be a set of such implied tag relationships known to the Stack Exchange software. Probably, we can cover most such real-world situations with a few dozen manually defined mappings.

Either those tags should be automatically added in all cases, or the relevant features of this site should take the mappings into account and pretend that all questions also have the implied tags set.

Maybe all implied tags can be added internally and just not shown on the question page. That way most components of Stack Exchange do not need to be changed. Just the places where a tag list is rendered.

Comment: Or maybe better: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262823/wouldnt-tag-inheritance-make-sense

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a good feature, I often miss tags on questions but rarely bother to re-tag. I should do that more often when editing.

I think though that the implicitly added tags you suggest must be visible, and that OP must be able to override the suggestions.

For example not every C# question is a .NET question. So a question purely dealing with the syntax of a language doesn't necessarily have to do with the runtime it runs on or the framework it talks to.

Comment: OK, good point. I did not see that case.

Comment: Related tag-suggestion-feature: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303409 Imho, there would also be value in an implied-tag-feature, but only for those cases where there really *cannot* be an exception. Like C++11 implies C++, but WINAPI does not quite imply windows, as there's wine.

Answer (score 3):

Tag hierarchies are an oft-proposed feature, though most were left on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com).
Most relevant posts on this site:

[Simple tag hierarchy to aid in searching / browsing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255245)
[Wouldn't tag inheritance make sense?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262823) ([Tag inheritance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272414))

And for features needing that:

[Expand close as duplicate gold badge coverage?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270691)
[Calculate reputation by tag and action](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268512)

Other related questions:

[Creating a "qtcore" tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256518)
[Adding extra, possibly unneeded, tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291857)
[Feature Request: Not tag inheritance, but tag suggestions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303409)
[Removing tags for supersets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254138)
[Would a tagging "metonym" feature be overkill?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252260)

Comment: Thanks for curating that list! Sad, that none of these discussions resulted in any action. Seems to be hard to make into a production-worthy feature.